# z value is not available in fragment shader in WebGL?

Tags: opencv, three.js, webgl, fisheye

I'm trying to apply [OpenCV's fisheye projection model](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d58/group__calib3d__fisheye.html) to this [demo](https://www.decarpentier.nl/downloads/lensdistortion-webgl/lensdistortion-webgl.html) (source code is [here](https://www.decarpentier.nl/downloads/lensdistortion-webgl.zip)) showing 3D cube using three.js developed by Giliam de Carpentier.

the above demo is already applied fisheye-like effect, but I need a real fisheye projection with a real camera calibration.

I started implementing a new fragment shader on it, but I noticed 3rd value (z) of position of vertex is always 0.
So, it's not possible to compute a=x/z, b=y/z in the formula of the projection model.

Since I'm very new to three.js and webGL, I could not figure out what's wrong with that.
Could you tell me how can I get z-axis value of a vertex position?

Thank you in advance.

**update:**
to reproduce the problem, please replace vertex shader by the following code in the lensdistortion-webgl.html.

```
vertexShader: [
    "void main() {",
    "vec3 vposition = position;",
    "if (position[2] == 0.0) { ",           // check if z value is zero.
    "  vposition[1] = 0.5 * vposition[1];", // if z value is zero, then shorten shaps along y-axis.
    "}",

    "gl_Position = projectionMatrix * (modelViewMatrix * vec4(vposition, 1.0));",

    "}"
].join("\n"),
```

you will see the shorten boxes that is shown only when z coordinate is zero.

Comment: Please don’t share code as zip file. Try to create a minimal, reproducible example that explains where you got stuck and add it to your question with code markups [ask]! The z coordinate is the distance from the projection plane and should be part of your 3d model.

Comment: Hi, Markus. thank you pointing out that. I added how to reproduce the problem. I could not create a minimal code because the code depends on js files under `examples/`  provided from three.js.